# Streamlining Code for multiple methods in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Still trying to get a handle on programming in Java, below is the code to a recent assignment in multiple methods that I've already submitted for college.

My query is, is it possible to streamline the code any to make it more effective as opposed going about it via a longer route.

1: Print highest value of an Array.
2: Print lowest value of an Array.
3: Print average value of Array.
4: Print number of occurrences of a specific word in a String.
5: Print the average word length of a string.

```
public class MaxMinAverage {
static int[] values = {1, 4, 3, 57, 7, 14, 7, 3, 10, 5, 4, 4, 10, 5, -88};
static String sentence = "the cat sat on the mat and the dog sat on the rug";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("MaxMinAverage.java\n=====================");
    System.out.println("Maximum value = "+getMaximum(values));
    System.out.println("Minimum value = "+getMinimum(values));
    System.out.println("Average Value =" +getAverage(values));
    System.out.println("Frequency of 'the' = "+getFrequency(sentence,"the"));
    System.out.println("Average word length = "+getAverageWordLength(sentence));
    }
    public static int getMaximum(int[]arr){
        int max = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            if(values[i] > max){
                    max = values[i];
                    }
            }
        return max;
     }
    public static int getMinimum(int[] arr){
        int min = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
            if(values[i] < min){
                    min = values[i];
                    }
            }
        return min;
    }
    public static float getAverage(int[] arr){
        float result = 0;
        for(float i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
             result = result + values[(int) i];
        }
        return result/values.length;
     }
    public static int getFrequency(String sentance, String word){
        String keyword = "the";
        String[] temp;
        String space = " ";
        temp = sentence.split(space);
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i].equals(keyword)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static float getAverageWordLength(String sentance){
        String characters = sentence.replaceAll("\\W","");
        float total = characters.length();
        float result = 0;
        String[] temp;
        String space = " ";
        temp = sentence.split(space);
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            result++;   
        }
        return total/result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? It looks fine.

Comment: You need to set initial values for `min` and `max` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` respectively.

Comment: if you are looking for streamlining go here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: You can have all the logic for the items 1-4 in a single loop which would improve the execution time of your program. But, I will suggest segregating the logic into different methods as you did is the right thing to do.

Comment: The code itself works fine, it was more a case of is it possible to get from A to B faster then going A to Z to B (which is what I feel I've done here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it more effective:

You could always use **DRY(Don't repeat yourself)** here and create a `ArrayUtils` class and keep all these methods there and generalize them so that you can reuse them.

```
public static int getMinimum(int[] arr){
        int min = arr[0];  //change here
        for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
            if(values[i] < min){
                    min = values[i];
                    }
            }
        return min;
    }
```

similar change for `max` method

Answer (score 0):

In `getMaximum` you probably want to `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE`; and in `getMinimum` you want `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`. Otherwise `getMaximum` will return 0 if all elements in the array is less than zero (so you return a value not in the array) and in getMinimum you will return 0 if all elements are greater than zero (which is also wrong).

Also, in `getMinimum` start iterating from index 1 meaning you miss index 0.

Furthermore, you don't use the the parameter of the methods, you use the `values` array directly. Say you invoked `getMinimum(someOtherArray)`, you would still calculate on `values`. Instead you should iterate over the array given as parameter like this:

```
public static int getMinimum(int[] arr){
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] < min){
                min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

This should of course be done for all methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the logical parts of `getMaximum`, `getMinimum` and `getAverage` in the same loop (same for `getFrequency` and `getAverageWordLength` in another one) as follow:

```java
public static void getMinMaxAvg(int[] values) {
    if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int min = values[0];
    int max = values[0];
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] < min) {
            min = values[i];
        } else if (values[i] > max) {
            max = values[i];
        }
        sum += values[i];
    }
    System.out.println("min = " + min);
    System.out.println("max = " + max);
    System.out.println("avg = " + ((float) sum / (i + 1)));
}

public static void getFreqAvg(String sentence, String word) {
    if (sentence == null || sentence.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (word == null || word.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    String[] words = sentence.replaceAll("^ *(.*?) *$", "$1").split(" +");
    int freq = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            freq++;
        }
        sum += words[i].length();
    }
    System.out.println("freq of \"" + word + "\" = " + freq);
    System.out.println("avg word length = " + ((float) sum / (i + 1)));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] values = { 1, 4, 3, 57, 7, 14, 7, 3, 10, 5, 4, 4, 10, 5, -88 };
    String sentence = " the  cat sat on the mat and the dog sat on the rug ";
    String word = "the";

    getMinMaxAvg(values);
    getFreqAvg(sentence, word);

}
```

Prints:

```
min = -88
max = 57
avg = 2.8125
freq of "the" = 4
avg word length = 2.642857
```